# Costa's loop questions, design, tracking and limitations

Tags: dsp-core

Why does Costa's loop PLL bandwidth need to be narrow? and why can't it track a certain frequency offset? and does that hold even if it has a filter with a pole at DC?

Comment: Please use appropriate tags! [tag:dsp-core] is about digital signal processors, i.e. about the physical chips. Your questions are very broad and make assumptions that don't apply universally; the second question is based on a fallacy; the third is confusing. Maybe it would be good to explain from where you get these questions!

Answer (score 2):

Costa's loop is related to traditional PLLs. One way of characterizing a PLL is by its loop bandwidth and damping factor. The damping factor determines the loop response (under-damped, over-damped or critically damped). The loop bandwidth determines how fast a PLL/Costas will achieve a "lock". The higher the loop bandwidth, the shorter the acquisition time. However, higher loop bandwidths result in higher tracking error (and hence higher locking threshold SNR - See graph below). Therefore, the loop bandwidth is a tradeoff between acquisition time and tracking error.  In some systems, the PLL/Costas start with a higher loop bandwidth before acquisition. After acquisition, the loop bandwidth is reduced to minimize tracking error. 
[image: Effect of loop bandwidth]

The following terms associated with general PLL can answer your second question

1. **Pull-in range**: is the maximum initial frequency difference between the input
   and VCO center frequencies both in positive and negative directions, for which
   the PLL eventually achieves the phase-locked condition. The pull-in range is
   related to the dynamics of the PLL
2. **Lock-in range**: is the frequency range over which the PLL achieves the
   phase-locked condition without cycle slips

A little Googling can help you to find the specific formulas of the two terms above for the Costas Loop.

Regards,

Moses.